# How to find the irregular part(with a peak) from a curve(2D-Array)?

Tags: c++

I have some curves of the following form, and I would like to remove the part within the green point and the yellow point. Does anyone know any fast algorithm which can do that?

The red point and the yellow point may be easy to find, the problem is the green point I think.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: you can find angle between Points[i], Points[i+1], Points[i+2]; for most Points it will be close to Pi, but for green, red and yellow points angle will differ from Pi.

Comment: @AndrewKashpur Thanks! But for each curve I have thousends of points. They are quite dense. The points Points[i], Points[i+1], Points[i+2]; may say nothing. And there may be other small noise inflences the result.

Comment: well if you have too many points, take every third (5th?, 10th?, depending on your data). More robust approach than angles: take subset of K consequent points, that gives you k-1 vectors, You can calculate math expectation and dispersion for this k-1 vectors, than compare dispersion to a certain threshold: if dispersion is above threshold, than declanation from general direction happened.You'll need to calibrate k, threshold and step between checks for it to work on your data.